# Flex spark list, onHover/onClick changes currentState

Tags: list, flex4, mouseevent, states

I'm using a Flex4 Spark list with a Tilelayout. In the itemrenderer, 4 states are defined.
The state changes on `MouseOver` and `MouseClick`, which is not my purpose.

This is some code:

```
 <s:List id="tileList" click="tileList_itemClick(event)" styleName="widgetList">
            <s:layout>
                <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="7" />
            </s:layout>
    </s:List> 
    var factory:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(ExamWidgetRenderer);
    tileList.itemRenderer = factory;
    tileList.dataProvider = items;
```

In the itemRenderer:

```
 <s:states>
        <s:State name="InitialState"/>
        <s:State name="Completed"/>
        <s:State name="Disabled"/>
        <s:State name="Locked"/>
    </s:states>
```

The states are set by the dataprovider.
There is no influence of an MouseEvent.

Has anyone, who also had this problem, solved this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try it`autoDrawBackground="false"` it may be solve your problem